# Hook Android Sytem API related to Text Output

Tags: android, windows, api, operating-system, hook

In Windows Programming, if you hook `TextOut，ExtTextOut，DrawText，DrawTextEx，PolyTextOut，TabbedTextOut` etc, you can almost catch the ouput of any software.

Are there similiar system apis you can hook on Android?

I want to capture the output of some apps.

PS: I have root permission!  I have got the target android app.

I can even install it on an android emulator on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have't root permissions, you can do it only for your own processt, his is not system wide. By using android NDK, as in [this](http://shadowwhowalks.blogspot.ru/2013/01/android-hacking-hooking-system.html) example, or [this](https://github.com/evilsocket/arminject)

Comment: I have root permission! I have got the target android app. I can even install it on an android emulator on Windows. Now can you tell me which system functions should I hook?